# GCP AI Platform Pipelines CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I have a Google Cloud Platform account and, basically, what I need is a Kubernetes cluster and an AI Platform pipeline inside that cluster. So far, I was able to create these components on the platform itself, but I need a script to do this initial setup automatically, without having to access the platform. From what I found on the documentation and the platform itself, the CLI provides a method to authenticate and create the cluster:

```
    # authenticate
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file KEY_FILE.json
    
    # create cluster
    gcloud beta container --project "_PROJECT_" clusters create "_CLUSTER" \
                          --zone "_ZONE_" \
                          --no-enable-basic-auth \
                          --cluster-version "_CLUSTER_VERSION_" \
                          --machine-type "_MACHINE_TYPE_" \
                          --image-type "_IMAGE_TYPE_" \
                          --disk-type "_DISK_TYPE_" \
                          --disk-size "_DISK_SIZE_" \
                          --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true \
                          --scopes "_SCOPES_" \
                          --num-nodes "_N_NODES_" \
                          --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
                          --enable-ip-alias \
                          --network "_NETWORK_" \
                          --subnetwork "_SUBNETWORK_" \
                          --default-max-pods-per-node "_MAX_PODS_" \
                          --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
                          --addons _ADDONS_ \
                          --enable-autoupgrade \
                          --enable-autorepair \
                          --max-surge-upgrade 1 \
                          --max-unavailable-upgrade 0
```

However, I could not find a way to do something similar to create the AI Platform pipeline.

Is it possible to do using only the CLI?

I noticed that the AI Platform Pipelines page has a "BETA" tag. Does this mean the CLI does not have a method to create these pipelines yet ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: at the moment I don't think this is supported through the Cloud SDK since as you mention this is product is still on beta, however, maybe in the future versions of the Cloud SDK it will be available

Comment: @rsalinas I still thinks it's strange that the CLI allows the user to authenticate, create the cluster, create notebook server instances but does not provide a way to create AI Platform Pipelines. But thanks for the answer :)